# How many clients on lower end iSCSI targets?

Tags: iscsi

Was wondering if anyone has built an iSCSI server on current AMD hardware. I ask because i am slowly implementing ccdisk on a 28 machine internet cafe. Now i am starting to question my build. I assembled a 6 core AMD FX6300 with 16 gigs of RAM controlling a hardware RAID 6 ; 4 x 2tb WDre drives array. The initiator teams so i purchased a quad pro NIC from Intel.

Is this going to be sufficient to run 28 machines or should i pop for a more robust AM3 cpu ?

Comment: I'd use two 2-port NICs rather than a single 4-port NIC.

Comment: I searched but obviously didnt ask my question correctly. I am more interested in knowing if this low end amd will have the jam. I will look up the differences in NIC hardware. I didnt think a quad would be any diiferent than two duals.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's regarding the NIC, CPU, RAM, or Storage.  No one can reasonably tell you whether any given set of hardware is fast enough for your needs.  Your best bet is to do your own testing to see what it can handle.

Comment: An iSCSI target is not especially CPU-intensive. If you are not going to use heavy-weight storage features like compression, online deduplication or CIFS (Windows shares), you will even get decent performance even out of an embedded device. You might want to look what [other storage appliances are/were using](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetApp_filer#Model_history) if you need a better idea for sizing.